# CSS question about overriding styles

Tags: html, css, forms, css-selectors

I have two css files, global.css and specific.css

In my HTML I have

```
<div class="someForm">
    <form>
        <input type="submit" class="submit red">
    </form>
</div>
```

In global.css I have `.someForm form input.submit {background-color: #ccc;}` as default.
In specific.css I have `.red {background-color: red;}`

I'm calling specific.css after global.css, but the button isn't turning red.  I stays the default grey "ccc".  I cannot edit specific.css or edit the old global.css styles. (older code relies on it.)  I can only add new CSS to global.  Is there something I can do to make the button red?

Answer (score 8):

Ironically, `.red` itself is a *less* specific selector than the global `.someForm form input.submit`. As a result, your submit button takes on a grey background from the global rule instead.

Anyway, you can duplicate the existing global rule (the first one), but attach the `.red` class selector to this one, and make it red like this:

```
.someForm form input.submit.red { background-color: red; }
```

Adding the extra `.red` class to this selector makes it more specific than the original `.someForm form input.submit` selector. Since your submit button has both classes, this new rule will be applied to it.

Comment: I'm not sure enough to post it as an answer, but would `!important` on the `.red` class work?

Comment: @cabaret: It certainly would, but I'd use a more specific selector instead. The specific.css file can't be modified anyway.

Comment: To expand on BoltClock's answer, the issue at hand is the "specificity" of your selector (in layman's terms your selector is not specific enough). Google the term 'CSS specificity' for more information on how specificity works and is calculated. Other topics you may want to look into are CSS Inheritance and Cascade.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the selector you have specified the global.css has a larger hierarchy than that in the specific. If you were to place. `someForm .red {background-color: red;}` It would work. Or you can use `{background-color: red !important;}` but that is a permanent override.

Comment: `.someForm .red` doesn't work, it's not specific enough to override the original.

Answer (score -1):

The selector in global.css is more specific than the one in specific.css, so it takes priority. However, you can apply the `!important` flag to the value in specific.css so that it takes precedence, like so:

`.red{background-color:red!important}`

Comment: specific.css must not be touched.

Comment: My mistake. He edited his question a few minutes after I responded.